# user input not passing through if statement in Python, but is able to pass through in Java

Tags: java, python

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to learn how to code simple String algorithms from my knowledge of Java.
I'm trying to recreate this code segment in Python from Java:

Java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] list = {"Yes", "No", "Maybe", "So"};
        String userInput = input.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            if(userInput.equals(list[i]))
            {
                System.out.println("oh baby");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my recreation in Python:

```
list = ["Yes", "No", "Maybe", "So"]
userInput = input()
for i in range(len(list)):
    if userInput is list[i]:
        print("oh baby")
```

but for some reason...in Python, it seems to not want to pass through the if statement.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe).

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe).

```py
list = ["Yes", "No", "Maybe", "So"]
userInput = input()
for i in range(len(list)):
    if userInput == list[i]:
        print("oh baby")
```

Comment: are Strings not considered objects in Python?

Answer (score 0):

```
test_list = ["Yes", "No", "Maybe", "So"]
user_input = input()
if user_input in test_list:
    print("oh baby")
```

This should work. Avoid using "list" as a variable as it is a function in Python. There is no need to iterate over the list as Python can use the keyword "in".

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_in.asp